# Improve Performance of Find and Replace in folder and subfolder files Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a java program that do find and replace  ( like when you do it in a text editor for example notepad++ ) in files of a folder and all sub-folders
well what i did is i created 4 functions the first function has folder path in the parameters
so it listed all the sub files  if it's a folder then list all the sub files again and then on RecursivePrint i check the extension of the file if it's a non readable file like images and compressed files then ignore otherwise i open the file using BufferedReader and check for the string and replace it with the new string

```
public void findWord(File pathToStart){
    // find word in every sub folders and subfiles.

    File[] filesInDirectory = pathToStart.listFiles(); // all sub files listed
    findWord = find.getText();
    replaceWord = replace.getText();
    driver();


}
public void driver(){ // drive all the files
    File dir = new File(path.getText());
    //fill here
    if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) 
    { 
        // array for files and sub-directories  
        // of directory pointed by maindir 
        File arr[] = dir.listFiles(); 
        
          
        // Calling recursive method 
        RecursivePrint(arr,0,0);  
   } 

public void RecursivePrint(File[] arr,int index,int level)  //arr file array
 {  
    // terminate condition 
    if(index == arr.length) 
         return; 
       
     // tabs for internal levels 
     for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) 
         System.out.print("\t"); 
       
     // for files 
     if(arr[index].isFile()){ 
         
         
                 String fileNamee;
   
      
      fileNamee=arr[index].getAbsolutePath();
      
     
    
  if( fileNamee.contains(".png") == false && fileNamee.contains(".jpg") == false && fileNamee.contains(".jpeg") == false 
          && fileNamee.contains(".rawproto") == false&& fileNamee.contains(".apk") == false && fileNamee.contains(".pro") == false){
 modifyFile(fileNamee, findWord, replaceWord);
     
    System.out.println("\nDoing The Task");
}
else{
    //System.out.print("File Not Readaable might be img file or other  on-readable file");
}
  

         

     
     }
       
     // for sub-directories 
     else if(arr[index].isDirectory() && !(arr[index].getName().equals(".git"))) 
     { 
        

         // recursion for sub-directories 
         RecursivePrint(arr[index].listFiles(), 0, level + 1); 
     } 
        
     // recursion for main directory 
     RecursivePrint(arr,++index, level); 
}

  public static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString){
    File fileToBeModified = new File(filePath);
     
    String oldContent = "";
     
    BufferedReader reader = null;
     
    FileWriter writer = null;
     
    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified));
         
        //Reading all the lines of input text file into oldContent
         
        String line = reader.readLine();
         
        while (line != null) 
        {
            oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
             
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
         
        //Replacing oldString with newString in the oldContent
         
        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
         
        //Rewriting the input text file with newContent
         
        writer = new FileWriter(fileToBeModified);
         
        writer.write(newContent);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            //Closing the resources
             
            reader.close();
             
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

well this code is working perfectly but the problem is it takes too long even with a good pc for just a 64mb folder it's stay for more than 20 min so is there anyway that i can improve the performance of this program

Comment: I think narrowing down where the performance issue is is the first step. I suggest commenting out the lines that do the replacing and writing the new content to the file. Is that faster? If so add back the lines that write the content to the file, is it still fast? Add the lines that do the replacing is it still fast? This way you can narrow down the performance issues to specific functions

Comment: One hint: `oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();` reallocates and copies the entire file content for _every single line_ in the input file.  Have you read the Javadoc for `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Each file is independent. In other words, you don't have a situation where you have to modify a particular file before you modify another, particular file. Hence you could group the files and launch a separate thread for each group. You would probably also need to consider the maximum number of threads that could be created to run in parallel.

Comment: Also, consider what happens if you encounter, say, a `.jar` or `.exe` file?  Your program as currently written is a time bomb waiting to go off and destroy your operating system or valuable programs.  You cannot list all binary file types, so this approach is basically flawed.

Comment: @Abra That might be appropriate to consider AFTER the obvious inefficiencies are corrected.  Any gain from threading will be dwarfed by the other issues.  And, with I/O bound work, threading may or may not help.  In fact, if the filesystem is a spinning disk, it may just induce head thrashing and actually slow things down.  Multithreading should be done ONLY if the gain in performance outweighs the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

What is really slow, is to use String concatenation, `+`.
This can easily be hundreds times slower.

```
public static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString)
        throws IOException {
    Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
    String oldContent = Files.readString(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
    String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
    if (!newContent.equalsOldContent)) {
        Files.writeString(file, newContent, Charset.defaultCharset());
    }
}
```

There are other goodies in [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html), also for walking through all files, subdirectories recursively and such.